# How to query json stored as string in bigquery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to query json stored as string in bigquery table?
I have a table where value in a column (`subscriptions`) looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "application_fee_percent": null,
        "canceled_at": null,
        "created": 1500476240,
        "items": {
            "data": [{
                "created": 1500476240,
                "id": "s4nQMWJn4P1Lg",
                "metadata": {},
                "object": "subscription_item",
                "plan": {
                    "amount": 3,
                    "created": 1494270926,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "livemode": true,
                    "metadata": {
                        "currentlySelling": "true",
                        "features": "{\"shipping\": true,\"transactionFee\":0.00}",
                        "marketingFeatures": "[\"Unlimited products\"]"
                    },
                    "name": "Personal",
                    "object": "plan",
                    "statement_descriptor": null,
                    "trial_period_days": null
                },
                "quantity": 1
            }],
            "has_more": false,
            "object": "list",
            "total_count": 1,
            "url": "/v1/subscri3XwjA3"
        },
        "livemode": true,
        "metadata": {
            "test": "596f735756976"
        },
        "object": "suion",
        "quantity": 1
    }],
    "has_more": false,
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/cutions"
}
```

How can I select `application_fee_percent`, `features`, and `marketingFeatures`?

For `created`, I tried
`JSON_EXTRACT("subscriptions", "$.data[0].created")` 
but it's returning null.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the JSON that you shared is not valid (try pasting it into https://jsonlint.com/), so it won't be possible to use `JSON_EXTRACT` with it unless maybe there was a mistake in transcription.

Comment: That is my bad. I have a big value and I tried to make it smaller for the post and I messed up. Updating it and the new json is valid.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Below is for BgQuery SQL (please take attention to Note at the bottom of answer!)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT '''
    {
        "data": [{
            "application_fee_percent": null,
            "canceled_at": null,
            "created": 1500476240,
            "items": {
                "data": [{
                    "created": 1500476240,
                    "id": "s4nQMWJn4P1Lg",
                    "metadata": {},
                    "object": "subscription_item",
                    "plan": {
                        "amount": 2500,
                        "created": 1494270926,
                        "currency": "usd",
                        "id": "182463d635c6b6e43",
                        "interval": "month",
                        "interval_count": 1,
                        "livemode": true,
                        "metadata": {
                            "currentlySelling": "true",
                            "features": "{\'shipping\': true,\'transactionFee\':0.00}",
                            "marketingFeatures": "[\'Unlimited products\']"
                        },
                        "name": "Personal",
                        "object": "plan",
                        "statement_descriptor": null,
                        "trial_period_days": null
                    },
                    "quantity": 1
                }],
                "has_more": false,
                "object": "list",
                "total_count": 1,
                "url": "/v1/subscri3XwjA3"
            },
            "livemode": true,
            "metadata": {
                "test": "596f735630012756976"
            },
            "object": "subscription",
            "quantity": 1,
            "start": 1500476240,
            "status": "trialing",
            "tax_percent": 0.0,
            "trial_end": 1501685839,
            "trial_start": 1500476240
        }],
        "has_more": false,
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/cutions"
    }
  ''' AS subscriptions
)
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(subscriptions, "$.data[0].application_fee_percent") AS application_fee_percent,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(subscriptions, "$.data[0].created") AS created,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(subscriptions, "$.data[0].items.data[0].plan.metadata.currentlySelling") AS currentlySelling,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(subscriptions, "$.data[0].items.data[0].plan.metadata.features") AS features,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(subscriptions, "$.data[0].items.data[0].plan.metadata.marketingFeatures") AS marketingFeatures
FROM yourTable
```

The result is as expected

```sql
application_fee_percent created     currentlySelling  features marketingFeatures      
null                    1500476240  true              {'shipping': true,'transactionFee':0.00}  ['Unlimited products']
```

Please note: *your JSON is not valid for `features` and `marketingFeatures` - they consists double quotes inside double quotes - so as you can see I changed this in your example data  - but you need to fix that part of your application that produces it*

Added example of raw string use:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT R"""{
    "features": "{\"shipping\": true,\"productLimit\":5,\"discounts\": false,\"customDomain\": false, \"imageLimit\": 100,\"transactionFee\":0.03} "
  }""" AS subscriptions
)
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(subscriptions, '$.features') AS features
FROM YourTable
```

result is

```sql
features     
{"shipping": true,"productLimit":5,"discounts": false,"customDomain": false, "imageLimit": 100,"transactionFee":0.03}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you'd already posted basically the same thing so I'll delete my answer. The OP might want `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` for the two `features` fields if they are expected to be strings.

Comment: ugh! I was relying on python for that.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - no problem, sorry for getting it up few sec before you. Believe me  - in so many cases  - right before i am about to post answer -
 i see your answer just came so I am not posting - and in most cases it is almost identical  -
 i am so enjoying the fact that we think so similar :o)

Comment: I would like to know your thoughts on this. I am getting this from the source `"features": "{\"shipping\": true,\"productLimit\":5,\"discounts\": false,\"customDomain\": false, \"imageLimit\": 100,\"transactionFee\":0.03} "` How should I handle this so that I can use json_extract method on this?

Comment: somehow I really doubt that you actually have that exactly text in your table, but rather it looks like you copy it from output of something like select * or preview where `\` just used to escape quotes inside quotes. meantime if you want to apply json_extract to such string  - you should use `raw string` - see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#string-and-bytes-literals. Also see example i am about to add in my answer

Comment: Data at the source `"features": "{\"shipping\": true,\"productLimit\":5,\"discounts\": false,\"customDomain\": false, \"imageLimit\": 100,\"transactionFee\":0.03} "` Data

Comment: if you have this in your original source (per BigQuery) you might want to consider transforming it either before getting to bigquery are after  - right before applying json_extract. you should experiment around this. i will also do later today when time allow

Comment: Can you tell how to use raw string on a column instead of a string value like you have show above?

Comment: i think raw string is applicable to literals. if you can share small table with examples of your data, we might be able to look into it