# Array field in DataPrep is recognised as a string in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to use dataprep to wrangle my data for reporting.

However, the field that is supposed to be array is recognise as a string in bigquery.

Example Data:

```
{"name":"herman","age":34,"property":[{"address":"henry street","state":"vic"},{"address":"mount waverley","state":"vic"}]}
{"name":"Handry","age":61,"property":[{"address":"Balwyn","state":"vic"},{"address":"Clayton","state":"vic"}]}
```

Basically, I just want to make the some fields uppercase.(This is only a simple example, I have far complex transformation)
Here is the wrangle file:

```
flatten col: property
unnest col: property keys: 'state','address' markLineage: true
drop col: property
derive value: upper(property_address) as: 'upper_property_address'
drop col: property_address
derive value: upper(property_state) as: 'upper_property_state'
drop col: property_state
nest col: upper_property_state,upper_property_address as: 'column1'
derive value: list(column1, 1000) group: name as: 'column2'
drop col: column1,upper_property_address,upper_property_state
deduplicate
```

and lastly result in bigquery(in the table):

```
{"age":"61","name":"Handry","column2":"[{\"upper_property_state\":\"VIC\",\"upper_property_address\":\"BALWYN\"},{\"upper_property_state\":\"VIC\",\"upper_property_address\":\"CLAYTON\"}]"}
{"age":"34","name":"herman","column2":"[{\"upper_property_state\":\"VIC\",\"upper_property_address\":\"HENRY STREET\"},{\"upper_property_state\":\"VIC\",\"upper_property_address\":\"MOUNT WAVERLEY\"}]"}
```

I also ask this in google issue. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69773118

**Just wondering, anyone has this issue and has a workaround?** 
I know we can query JSON in biquery, which is described here:
[How to query json stored as string in bigquery table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199120/how-to-query-json-stored-as-string-in-bigquery-table)

but it makes the query complex and I want to avoid it.

Comment: Is this a one-time transformation that you need to make? You could load the data into BigQuery and then run a query that uppercases the strings and writes to a table, for instance.

Comment: No, this is only a simple example. The transformation is far complex from this. Anyway, this is a limitation from bigquery as stated https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Using-BigQuery_59736092

but, I would appreciate if anyone else has this issue and manage to get the workaround

Comment: I think the workaround is to use BigQuery directly for the transformation :)