# Querying JSON value in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-workspace

I have a BigQuery table ("activity") where one column ("groups") contains a JSON value (the table is an export of Google Workspace logs).

I'd like to be able to select rows from the table based on the `group_email` JSON value in the `group` column. I checked the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data#extract_values_as_strings), but my queries always return null. I tried:

```
SELECT
  record_type,
  email,
  JSON_VALUE('groups.group_email') AS group_email
```

but got null. I also tried using the column index of `group_email`

```
SELECT
  record_type,
  email,
  JSON_VALUE('groups[4]') AS group_email
```

but no luck. I tried these same combinations as part of the WHERE statement but got the same results:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `company.workspace_prod.activity`
WHERE
  record_type = 'groups'
  and
  JSON_VALUE('groups.group_email') = 'everyone@company.com'
LIMIT
  10
```

I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199120/how-to-query-json-stored-as-string-in-bigquery-table) but using `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('groups', "$.groups[0].group_email") AS group_email` also returns null

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should provide sample data so we can reproduce and fix your problem. see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

You may try below approach.

```
SELECT
  record_type,
  email,
  JSON_VALUE(groups,'$.group_email') AS group_email
FROM
  `company.workspace_prod.activity`
```

You may refer to this [JSON function Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) for more details.

Please see screenshot of my testing below using the correct syntax for JSON_VALUE.

**SAMPLE DATA:**

| int64_field_0 | string_field_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | "This is a string" |
| 3 | {"id": 10, "name": "Alice"} |

**QUERY RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: I get `Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword GROUPS at [3:16]`, I tried wrapping the whole thing in quotes but then get `No matching signature for function JSON_EXTRACT for argument types: STRING. Supported signature: JSON_EXTRACT(STRING, STRING) at [3:3]` strings seperated by a period returns `Syntax error: Unexpected string literal '$.group_email' at [3:25]`

Comment: @IanHyzy I have updated my posted answer including proof of testing. If it still doesn't work, kindly provide sample data to properly reproduce on my end.

Comment: @IanHyzy If you find my answer helpful, you may upvote/accept it for the benefit of the community in the future that may encounter the same use case.

Answer (score 0):

though I am late but I am able to get via

```
SELECT
  record_type,
  email,
  json_extract(groups,'$.group_email') AS group_email
FROM
  `company.workspace_prod.activity`
```